# How to set ServerListRefreshInterval in ribbon load balancer?

Tags: java, spring, load-balancing, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

I'm using Spring, Eureka and Ribbon. I want to change the refresh interval for ribbon. While reading the documentation, I found out that I should set the following property:

```
my-service.ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval=99999
```

However, it doesn't help because when I create a load balancer, Spring uses the following constructor

```
   public DynamicServerListLoadBalancer(IClientConfig clientConfig, IRule rule, IPing ping, 
        ServerList<T> serverList, ServerListFilter<T> filter) {
    this(
            clientConfig,
            rule,
            ping,
            serverList,
            filter,
            new PollingServerListUpdater()
    );
```

And this constructor doesn't use my property.

Comment: Which version of spring-cloud-netflix are you using ?

Comment: @Berger Camden.SR7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at this topic : [How to override the ribbon.serverListRefreshInterval default value in Spring Cloud Ribbon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567078/how-to-override-the-ribbon-serverlistrefreshinterval-default-value-in-spring-clo)

The problem is related to this bug : [ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval ignored #1304](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1304).

The bug has been solved in [spring-cloud-netflix 1.3.0.RC1](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/milestone/37?closed=1) on March 2017 .

You are using [Spring Cloud Camden.SR7](https://spring.io/blog/2017/05/08/spring-cloud-camden-sr7-released) which uses `Spring Cloud Netflix 1.2.7.RELEASE`, where the bug wasn't fixed yet.

Either force the use of spring-cloud-netflix 1.3.0 or above, or switch to a [Spring Cloud version](https://spring.io/blog/category/releases) that contains this kind of dependency, e.g [Spring Cloud Edgware.SR2](https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/09/spring-cloud-edgware-sr2-released) ([Maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-parent/Edgware.SR2)) which uses `Spring Cloud Netflix 1.4.3.RELEASE`

Comment: Thank you. It's help me, but now the clientConfig doesn't see  my-service.ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval property? Can you help with this problem? I can fix it with use   ConfigurationManager.loadPropertiesFromResources("sample-client.properties"); but I think that this is not a good way

Comment: Sorry I have no clue why your properties aren't found.

Comment: Maybe you could try a version of Spring Cloud nearest to Camden.SR7, maybe Dalston.RELEASE (Maven : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-parent/Dalston.RELEASE) which uses Spring Cloud Netflix 1.3.0 : https://spring.io/blog/2017/04/12/spring-cloud-dalston-released

Comment: It doesn't help