# IClientConfig ribbon doesn't read properties from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, properties, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I created `IClientConfig`

```
@Bean
public IClientConfig ribbonClientConfig() {
    final DefaultClientConfigImpl config =
            DefaultClientConfigImpl.getClientConfigWithDefaultValues("my-service", "ribbon");
    return config;
}
```

And I have in applications properties `my-service.ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval=211123`. However, Ribbon configuration doesn't pick this property up.

Comment: how do you know that ribbon didn't read your property

Comment: @pvpkiran I enabled debug mode and looked PollingServerListUpdater constructor  I saw that property didn't apply also I didn't see this property in config

Comment: can you show your complete clientconfig

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567078/how-to-override-the-ribbon-serverlistrefreshinterval-default-value-in-spring-clo